# How to get the Nth row (or record) with Datamapper

Tags: datamapper

I'm looking for a more datamappery way of doing the following (since the code below is dependent on sqlite):

```
id = repository(:default).adapter.query(
  'SELECT id FROM ads ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1'
)
@ad = Ad.get(id)
```

My hope was to do something like:

```
@ad = Ad.get(:offset=>rand(Ad.all.count))
```

or

```
@ad = Ad.find(:offset=>rand(Ad.all.count), :limit=>1)
```

Basically I'm just looking for a way to get a row by offset or row number. Apologies if this has been asked already, I'm not sure what vocabulary to search for as I'm new to both Ruby and Datamapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request `Ad.first :offset => rand(Ad.count)`, but it invokes 2 SQL statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "ads"
SELECT "id" FROM "ads" ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1
```

Also you can use raw SQL:

```
repository.adapter.select "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: The `Ad.first :offset => n` part is what I was looking for in this case, thanks tons!  Though in a real app I'd just use the raw sql, so thanks for that too.